# Access pipeline variables via DevOps SSH task

Tags: bash, ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an SSH task in an Azure devops pipeline which connects to another target server to perform a deployment.

The target server does not have any of my pipeline's variables, nor do I have any means of passing them through the standard SSH Task. i.e., if I run `pwd`, none of my variables display.

Some of the variables are passwords.

What is the easiest way to pass these to my remote server?

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the Powershell on target machine task could help you achieve set variables in remote pipeline? Feel free to leave comment if you still has any puzzle or issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PowerShell on Target Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops) task with the PS script that set variable can help you to achieve this.

This task can help you connect the remote server then finish the powershell script.

For set variable script, you can check with this format `Write-Verbose -verbose`:

```
Param(
  [string]$psw
)
Write-Verbose "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NewPSWVariable]$psw" -verbose
```

[image]

I wrote the script in `.ps1` file, then choose **file path**, call and pass the value to the parameter in **PowerShell on Target Machine** task.

What I used here is `Write-Verbose`. This can help to print out the variable into console which can help to debug the log.

Comment: The *Powershell on Target Machine* Task doesn't really fit my requirements. It requires a Username/ Password to connect. I'm connecting to a Ubuntu machine via a *SSH Service Connection*.

Comment: Also, it doesn't allow mapping secret Variables either - The secret gets blanked out ... So there's no way to access these on the remote secret.